# Python: Generating a "set of tuples" from a "list of tuples" that doesn't take order into consideration

Tags: python, list, tuples

If I have the list of tuples as the following:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]
```

I would like to remove duplicate tuples (duplicate in terms of both content and order of items inside) so that the output would be:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Or

```
[('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')]
```

I tried converting it to set then to list but the output would maintain both `('b', 'a')` and `('a', 'b')` in the resulting set!

Comment: ... put all the items in a set, then  create a list from the set entries - this has probably been asked before

Comment: well your problem is that `('a','b') != ('b','a')` or more specifically, `hash(('a','b')) != hash(('b','a'))`. Do an initial list comprehension that sorts each tuple then convert to a set

Comment: also, you should probably reword your question since "duplicate in terms of both content and order of items inside" implies that you would want `('a','b')` and `('b','a')` to not be equal....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
a = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]
b = list(set([ tuple(sorted(t)) for t in a ]))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

**Let's break this down :**

If you sort a tuple, it becomes a sorted list.

```
>>> t = ('b', 'a')
>>> sorted(t)
['a', 'b']
```

For each tuple `t` in `a`, sort it and convert it back to a tuple.

```
>>> b = [ tuple(sorted(t)) for t in a ]
>>> b
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Convert the resulting list `b` to a set : values are now unique. Convert it back to a list.

```
>>> list(set(b))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Et voilà !

Note that you can skip the creation of the intermediate list `b` by using a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead of a [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

```
>>> list(set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in a))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: Good, except that you don't need to actually create the intermediate list `set([ tuple(sorted(t)) for t in a ])`. `set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in a)` instead.

Comment: True, this is not an OP requirement. But he expects an output like `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]`, so I figured it has to be a list.

Comment: The final form has to be a list; the intermediate list comprehension is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. You're right. I'll just keep my answer as is, since it's easier to break it down. :)

Comment: This doesn't work in the case: `[('b','a'), ('c','d'), ('b','a')]`. The output should be `[('b','a'), ('c','d')]` but your code outputs `[('a','b'), ('c','d')]`. The order within tuple shouldn't matter while comparing with other tuples -- but output should contain the original tuples -- not modified tuples.

Answer (score 6):

If you did not mind using a frozenset with a set:

```
l = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]

print(set(map(frozenset,l)))
{frozenset({'a', 'b'}), frozenset({'c', 'd'})}
```

You can convert back to tuple if preferable:

```
l = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]

print(list(map(tuple,set(map(frozenset ,l)))))
[('a', 'b'), ('d', 'c')]
```

Or using a set and reversing the order of the tuples:

```
l = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]

seen, pairs = set(), []
for a,b in l:
    if (a,b) not in seen and (b,a) not in seen:
        pairs.append((a,b))
    seen.add((a,b))
```

Answer (score 4):

This can solve your problem if order is not important.

```
a=[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]


a=map(tuple,[sorted(i) for i in a])

print list(set(a))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't make any assumption about the length or original internal order of the tuples.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, actually previous one was okay. lol. I just preferred  your's one because it liked the shorthand, but i didn't notice it won't sort the list element unfortunately, rather it sorts the list itself.

Comment: yep meant `a = map(tuple, map(sorted, l))`, if it were python2 then `imap` would be better

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a potential second solution if anyone has a use case where "first come, first serve" might matter.

For example, say we take three lists and merge them into a list of tuples:

```py
# Make some lists (must be same size) 
a = [1,1,1,2,8,6,1]
b = [2,4,6,1,4,21,69]
c = [2,8,21,2,1,1,8]

# Lists to list of tuples
arr = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    new_row = (a[i],b[i],c[i])
    arr.append(new_row)
```

Such that our original array looks like:

```
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 4, 8)
(1, 6, 21)
(2, 1, 2)
(8, 4, 1)
(6, 21, 1)
(1, 69, 8)
```

In our case, we want to remove items like (2,1,2) and (8,4,1) as they're equivalent to (1,2,2) and (1,4,8) respectively.
To do this, we can use a new empty list called `filtered` or something, and `itertools.permutations()` on each tuple in the original array.
First, we check if any permutation of each item is present in the `filtered` list.
If not, we add. If it is, we skip the duplicate.

```py
filtered = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
    it = itertools.permutations(arr[i])
    perms = []
    for p in it:
        perms.append(p)  
    check = any(item in perms for item in filtered)
    if not check: 
        filtered.append(arr[i])
```

Now if we iterate over `filtered` and print, we see our truncated list of tuples:

```
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 4, 8)
(1, 6, 21)
(1, 69, 8)
```

Note that we're left with the first instance of each tuple of numbers, and not working via a `set` guarantees the same order of elements when iterating over the filtered list.

Only thing I'm not 100% on is the time/space complexity of doing it this way -- if anyone has feedback I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score -1):

Built-in types to the rescue:

```
data = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]
set(map(frozenset, data))
{frozenset({'a', 'b'}), frozenset({'c', 'd'})}
```